# Upper bound on number of triples

Tags: combinatorics

We choose arbitrarily 100 lattice points in the coordinate plane. Let M be the number
of triples (A, B, C) of distinct points chosen from these 100 points such that A and B
have the same y-coordinate, and B and C have the same x-coordinate. Prove that the
greatest possible value of M is 8100.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: 8100 looks like a square with dots on every lattice point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a short proof. Let $C$ be one of the maximal configuration (that maximses $M$). $C$ can always be modified to a square structure such that $M$ is non-decreasing, hence $M=9*9*100=8100$.

> EXplicit Construction:

Consider re-construction of $C$, as in our intuition: ($C$ is assumed to be a structure on lattice point only.)

1. consider a $10 \times 10$ square, translate C such that it is mostly covered in the square.
2. if there is an empty row/column in this square, move one row/column (that have maximal number of points outside the square) outside the square to that row/column without disturbing the orignal configuration.

   (meaning that if points in that row/column have different coordinates as other points, then its new coordinates are again different.)

Denote the new configuration $C'$.

If there is a row with ($n$ elements) in the square with a 'hole'and also a point $X$ outside the square in the same row. Move $X$ to the hole, then $M$ is not changed.

Now reorder each row in decreasing number of elements in each row. which is in a row echelon form, ensure that the top left corner is in the top left corner of the square. (M not changed since 'row/column operation' don't change $M$.

Suppose $C'$ is not a square now, let $Y$ be the last element in the bottom row, place $Y$ to the last of the second last row (if these two rows have different number element. If not, place it to the third, etc), then $M$ is non-decreasing.

This operation stops only if number of element in each row are equal. Hence $C'$ becomes a rectangle.

Since we can proceed from any $C$ to a rectangular ($a \times b$) configuration, hence we can maximise $M$ as follows, $M=(a-1)(b-1)*100$ & $a*b=100$

Maximised if it is a square, hence we have $M=9*9*100=8100$.